# how to update file upload to db with uplodify in C# without ashx file

Tags: c#, uploadify

i want to update database with the details of the file uploaded using the uplodify jquery control,i have uploaded the file using that,but the code behind is handle in an .ashx file which uses the process request to upload file to server, while using that it calls DB each time considering the no of files(ie if i have 3 files to upload (**multiple case**) then it calls DB 3 times....)

how can i manage that, or is it possible not to use ashx file.. instead use the page cs file to handle the server action...

please help...

Comment: It makes me sad this has no answer.